# Can't boot Fedora from Kali's Grub

Tags: fedora, windows, grub2, kali-linux, dual-boot

I've had Windows 10 and Fedora 24 installed, dual-booting, and it has been fine, but I just installed Kali in the remaining 200 GB, and the bootloader it installed can't boot Fedora. If I go into my UEFI setup and boot from the bootloader that Fedora installed, it boots perfectly, but if I try to boot Fedora from the bootloader that Kali installed, it says it's in emergency mode, and I get a login prompt, but no GUI whatsoever. I'd like to be able to boot my three operating systems in the same place. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to attempt this as well.  From what I've read elsewhere, Kali doesn't include lvm in their default initrd.  I'd suggest installing lvm and rebuilding initrd.  Alternatively, reinstalling Fedora will likely result in getting the Fedora grub image, which should boot Kali fine.